# while loop check box is checked or not in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

**Edit :** Here I am going through the loop and I don't know how to do checkbox checked or not using php. Please check my code and let me know what is required to add in the code.

Please help. Thanks in Advance

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);

$select1 = "select * from $menu_table where status='A' order by menu_si_no asc";
$result1 = $con->query($select1) or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($data1 = $result1->fetch_array())
{
$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);
$selectac = "select * from $access_table where id='".$_GET['id']."'";
$resultac = $con->query($selectac) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$dataac = $resultac->fetch_array();

?> 
<li class="menu-list">

        <span style="color:#ff0000;"><?php echo $data1['menu_name']; ?></span>

        <span ><input type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $data1['menu_name']; ?>"></span>
        <?php
        $con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);

        $select2 = "select * from $submenu_table where menu_id='".$data1['id']."' and status='A'";
        $result2 = $con->query($select2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $count2 = $result2->num_rows;
        while($data2 = $result2->fetch_array())
        {
            $con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);

            $select3 = "select * from $access_table";
            $result3 = $con->query($select3) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $count3 = $result3->num_rows;
            while($datas = $result3->fetch_array())
            {   
                $ac_id[$j] = $datas['submenu_id'];
        ?>  
            <ul class="child-list">
               <span style="color:#1f30ef;width:150px;">

               <input type="checkbox"  name="submenu[]" value="<?php echo $data2['id']; ?>"><?php echo $data2['submenu']; ?></span>                           
               <span class="ch_box" style="width:100px;">
               <input type="checkbox" name="add[]" value="<?php echo $data2['id']; ?>">Add 
               <input type="checkbox"   name="edit[]" value="<?php echo $data2['id']; ?>">Edit 
               <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="<?php echo $data2['id']; ?>">Delete</span>
            </ul>
          <?php 
            }
        }

        ?>
</li>
<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: Whats your question? Its uncleared...

Comment: Pleas format your code and add some explanation to your question

Comment: Hi guys.   i have 10 submenus from my table each submenus having add edit delete checkboxes.. for assigning menu access priorities to the user.. then i want to check which menus are i assigned

Comment: how to check checkbox is checked in if condition and  values comes from two while loops

Answer (score 0):

your question is uncleared.

> assume 'edit' is a column in your table, if it is 1 it checked else unchecked

```
<input type="checkbox"   name="edit[]" value="<?php echo $data2['id']; ?>"
    <?php echo ($data2['edit'] == 1)? 'checked=""' : ''? >
```

Comment: sorry.. i have multiple checkboxes. so how i do check the all checkboxes

Comment: try this inside the loop
 <input type="checkbox"   name="add[]" value="<?php echo $data2['id']; ?>"
    <?php echo ($data2['add'] == 1)? 'checked=""' : ''? >

 <input type="checkbox"   name="delete[]" value="<?php echo $data2['id']; ?>"
    <?php echo ($data2['delete'] == 1)? 'checked=""' : ''? >

Comment: <?php echo ($data2['add'] == 1)? 'checked=""' : ''? > that ==1 is dynamic numbers from another table.. i need to check two values from two tables

Comment: i assume edit,add,delete are three different column in the table

Comment: here i have used the **edit,add, delete** as flag. according to my suggestion if checked use '1' else '0' for the columns.

Comment: thanks ji... i havemutliple checkboxes one is submenu 2.add 3.edit 4.delete each checkboxes having multiple values like (1)12.. (2)12,13... (3)32,34,45.... (4) 23,45,87 .. so only having no output still now..

Comment: how to check checkbox is checked in if condition and  values comes from two while loops